# I need a variable in SQL to take the values of the Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, variables, sql-delete

I am trying to get this to work with @FileIntID having multiple values pulled from a table.  I have tried many different ways.  The only thing I had left to try was a count loop and select a different row until null, but there has to be an easier way.  Any help would be appreciated.  The code works great if I Set the @FileIntID and remove the temp deletion table, but I don't want to have to do this for over 3000 entries.  I also don't want to output the values to excel and add commas for each scenario.

```
DECLARE @AccountID as Int, @FileIntID as BigInt

Set @AccountID = 758231

Declare @DeletionTable Table (FileIntId BigInt);
Insert Into @DeletionTable
(
    FileIntID 
)
SELECT FileIntID
FROM [MDSCommonDB1].[Document].[Metadata] m
INNER JOIN Document.entities e on e.EntityIntID = m.EntityIntID and  e.EntityType  = m.EntityType
inner join document.EntityStorageArea s on s.EntityIntID = e.EntityIntID and s.EntityType  = m.EntityType and s.StorageType = 'E'
where StrgCatagory = 'E' and m.FilePath NOT LIKE '%'+ e.EntityName+'%'

Select @FileIntID = (Select FileIntID from @DeletionTable)

DECLARE @FirmIntID as BigInt

Select @firmIntID = FirmIntID from [Common].[FirmAccount] with (nolock)
where AccountID = @AccountID

Select @FileIntID = m.FileIntId from [Document].[Metadata] m with (nolock)
where m.[FirmIntID]= @firmIntID and m.FileStatus = 'T' and m.FileIntId = @FileIntID

Delete FROM [Document].FileAudit
Where  FileIntID = @FileIntID and FirmIntID =@firmIntID 

Delete [Document].FileAuditLatest
Where FileIntID = @FileIntID                                      

Delete FROM [Document].FileVersion
Where  FileIntID = @FileIntID

Delete FROM [Document].[PublishDetail] 
Where  FileIntID = @FileIntID and FirmIntID = @firmIntID

Declare @fileDiscussion TABLE (FileDiscussionIntID bigint)
Declare @userGroupFilePermission TABLE (UserGroupFilePermissionIntID bigint)

INSERT INTO @fileDiscussion
(
     FileDiscussionIntID
)
SELECT [FileDiscussion].[FileDiscussionIntID] 
FROM [Document].[FileDiscussion] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE [FileDiscussion]. FileIntID = @FileIntID and [FileDiscussion].FirmIntID = @firmIntID

DELETE FROM [Document].[FileDiscussionNotification] 
WHERE [FileDiscussionNotification].[FileDiscussionIntID] in (SELECT     FileDiscussionIntID FROM @fileDiscussion)

DELETE FROM [Document].[FileDiscussion] 
WHERE [FileDiscussion].[FileDiscussionIntID] in (SELECT FileDiscussionIntID FROM @fileDiscussion)

INSERT INTO @userGroupFilePermission
(
    UserGroupFilePermissionIntID
)
SELECT [UserGroupFilePermission].[UserGroupFilePermissionIntID] 
FROM [Document].[UserGroupFilePermission] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE [UserGroupFilePermission].FileIntID = @FileIntID and [UserGroupFilePermission].FirmIntID = @firmIntID

DELETE FROM [Document].[UserGroupFilePermissionDetail] 
WHERE [UserGroupFilePermissionDetail].[UserGroupFilePermissionIntID] in (SELECT UserGroupFilePermissionIntID FROM @userGroupFilePermission)

DELETE FROM [Document].[UserGroupFilePermission] WHERE
[UserGroupFilePermission].[UserGroupFilePermissionIntID] in (SELECT  UserGroupFilePermissionIntID FROM @userGroupFilePermission)

DELETE FROM [Document].[Filegroupdetail] 
WHERE [FileIntID] = @FileIntID


DELETE FROM [Document].TaskAssignment
Where  FileIntID = @FileIntID

DELETE  FROM [Document].[PortalFileAudit]
WHERE [FileIntID] = @FileIntID and FirmIntID = @firmIntID

/* Start FK Reference Delete */

Delete [Document].[MultiuserDirectEdit]
Where FileIntID = @FileIntID  AND FirmIntID = @firmIntId

Delete [Document].[NamingChangeFiles]
Where FileIntID = @FileIntID  AND FirmIntID = @firmIntId

Delete [Document].[OfflineSyncFiles]
Where FileIntID = @FileIntID

Delete [Document].[RecycleBin]
Where FileIntID = @FileIntID  AND FirmIntID = @firmIntId

Delete [Document].[RoutingStatus]
Where FileIntID = @FileIntID  AND FirmIntID = @firmIntId

/* End FK Reference Delete */  

Delete FROM [Document].SearchMetadata
Where  FileIntID = @FileIntID and FirmIntID = @firmIntID

Delete FROM [Document].Metadata
Where FileIntID = @FileIntID and FirmIntID = @firmIntID
```

Comment: If you are going to use a delimited list you will need to split or parse that list in your procedure. Here is a great article on the topic. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a variable.   You already have the IDs in the `@DeletionTable`.   Just join to the Deletion table instead of using the variable.

For instance in the first case where you use the variable:

```
Delete FROM [Document].FileAudit
Where  FileIntID = @FileIntID and FirmIntID =@firmIntID
```

Do this instead:

```
Delete FROM fa
FROM [Document].FileAudit fa
INNER JOIN @DeletionTable dt
  ON fa.FileIntID = dt.FileIntID 
Where   FirmIntID =@firmIntID
```

And so on in all the other cases.

I'm not even sure why you're doing this:

```
Select @FileIntID = m.FileIntId from [Document].[Metadata] m with (nolock)
where m.[FirmIntID]= @firmIntID and m.FileStatus = 'T' and m.FileIntId = @FileIntID
```

If it's to restrict the file ids in the variable, then just include that as part of the first query that populates `@DeletionTable`

Comment: Thank You Thank You Thank You